# Meaning of "でも" in "食事でもどうですか？"

Tags: grammar, nuances, questions, particle-でも

I've found this sentence on alc.co.jp

> 食事**でも**どうですか

and I am puzzled as to meaning this でも conveys. How does it differ from

> 食事**は**どうですか

This would be my first choice but which, according to Google, is used less often?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This でも is used to mean "〜 or something", usually in regards to suggestions.  It leaves room for other options.

> - 食事**でも**どうですか　→　How about something to eat (or something else)?
> - お茶に**でも**いかない？　→　Would you like to go out for tea maybe?

---

参照

- [The use of でも and ででも in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13463/78)