# "事故にでもあったのではあるまいか。" grammar help please?

Tags: grammar, particle-でも

I came across this example in a textbook, and I can't figure out the grammar of the 2nd sentence:

> 彼から来るはずの連絡がない。事故にでもあったのではあるまいか。

ok:

> The correspondence from him that was expected has not come. `事故にでもあった`のではあるまいか。

I've no idea what `事故にでもあった` means. I can only imagine tokenizing as:

> 事故、に、でも、あった

maybe I can imagine:

> 事故、に、合った。 `I had an accident`

Not sure what to make of that `でも`... I don't know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21519/meaning-of-%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82-in-%E9%A3%9F%E4%BA%8B%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B

Comment: @mirka actually, should I have written "事故に遭った"?

Comment: Yes, that's right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ～にでも makes the sentence mean 'Could he have been involved in an accident or such?' It just makes the sentence politer than ～に alone. The last bit is a little odd too: ～のではあるまいか is a somewhat archaic way of saying ～のではないだろうか. The construction is used for offering a suggestion.