# Meaning of なければ + 分かる訳ないだろ

Tags: meaning

My question is about the sentence "領にでも行かなきゃ分かる訳ないだろ", meaning: "You'd have to go to the territory to find out (what is happening)"

I know that **なきゃ** from **行かなきゃ** is an abbreviation of なければ, and when used together with a verb means that it is something one must do, on this case it would translate to **"Must go"**

I also know that 訳ない when used together with a verb adds a meaning of "there's no way to do X", on this case, ****"there's now way to know"****

And given that でも means "But" and 領 means "territory", I can't seen to understand how this sentence can mean "You'd have to be in X to know that".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> なきゃ from 行かなきゃ is an abbreviation of なければ

This is absolutely correct.

---

> it would translate to "Must go"

This is not wrong, but not necessarily correct in this context.

---

## 行かなければ / 行かなきゃ

The literal translation is, "If I don't go...". That's it. With a couple of words attached the following may happen:

- "行かなければいい" (Don't need to go)
- "行かなければ宝くじが当たる" (Win the lottery if I don't go)
- "行かなければ結婚して幸せになれる" (Marry and live a happy life if I don't go)

What about now? Do you really have to go? I'd rather stay.

---

But as you mentioned, if you just say "行かなければ…", which no one actually says in real life excepts for emo kids, this **implicitly** is equivalent to "行かなければ**ならない**". This would mean "If I don't go, (it) won't work" = "I shall/must go".

But in your case, the consequence of not going is "not being able to know":

> 行かなければ (if one doesn't go)
> 分かる訳ない (there's no way one will know)

Notice it never says one **must** go.

---

## Outcome

With the above in mind, translate as follows:

- 領にでも + 行かなきゃ + 分かる訳ない
- To the 領 + if one doesn't go + (there's) no way to know

Shuffle them around:

- There's no way to know (what is happening) if one doesn't go to the 領

Which matches your translation:

- You'd have to go to the territory to find out (what is happening)

---

## にでも

> でも means "But"

Again, you are not wrong, but not correct here as it's "〜**に**でも". Check out this post for the usage: ["事故にでもあったのではあるまいか。" grammar help please? [duplicate]](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29499/%e4%ba%8b%e6%95%85%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a7%e3%82%82%e3%81%82%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a7%e3%81%af%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b%e3%81%be%e3%81%84%e3%81%8b-grammar-help-please) . It's tagged as a duplicate but I think this is the better match for your case.

Comment: I believe this でも is [this でも](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/94404/5010). It indicates 領に行く is technically one of the options.

Comment: By my understanding 行かなければいい is more like _"shouldn't go"_ rather than _"don't need to go"_, no?

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add a more detailed breakdown here, since this seems to be the core of what caused the initial difficulty.

> when used together with a verb means that it is something one must do

なければ is two separate parts: the な is the leftover part of ない (in turn from transforming 行く into 行かない), and then ければ transforms that i-adjective [by making it conditional](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/i-adjective-conditional-form-kereba/).

It simply considers the *hypothetical of not* doing something. "When used together with a verb", the connotation of "must" comes from the bad consequence in that verb. So it's not "I must go" (with some unclear relationship to the following verb), but "... if I don't go". In this case, *there's no way to understand what is happening, unless I go.*

Japanese doesn't have "have to" as a modal the way that English does; the general pattern is this kind of hypothetical + consequence construct. See also constructs like Xしてしかない: not "must do X", but "other-than-doing-X does not exist" (in more natural English, "doing anything but X is not an option").

---

You might also find it worthwhile to understand 訳ない as more than just a collocation. 訳 is a noun with glosses like "reason, method, way"; the entire preceding clause (not just the verb, though such a clause could consist of only a verb - as it does here, with 分かる) is used attributively to describe that noun - thus, X訳 is "a way that X [could be the case]". Then, that whole thing is the が-marked subject of ない - the が has been dropped here, but is sometimes used explicitly; see for example the anime title 俺の妹がこんなに可愛いわけがない.