# The function of "demo" in the following sentence: 遥か彼方で炎でも燃え盛っているように、紅蓮の光は形を変え、踊る。

Tags: grammar, particle-でも

So in the sentence below what would be the grammar function of 炎でも?

> 遥か彼方で炎でも燃え盛っているように、紅蓮の光は形を変え、踊る。

I can understand the overall meaning, but I am struggling with how to phrase this part.

Comment: [This](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21519/45489) should answer your question.