# にでもなって and にもなって

Tags: grammar

there was a problem that required me to fill the blank with correct option that is provide with.

> 娘は、社会人（　　）朝一人で起きられない。私が起こさないといつまでも寝ている。
>
> a) にでもなって　b) にもなって

what is the correct answer, and why?

Comment: what is the difference between A and B?

Answer (score 3):

Xに**でも**なって means "to become X **or something**". This でも is a particle that means "or something (similar)". See: [Meaning of "でも" in "食事でもどうですか？"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21519/5010)

- プロのシェフにでもなったような気分だ。
  I feel like I've become a professional chef or something.
- 小説家にでもなって自分の物語を世界に伝えたい。
  I want to become something like a novelist to share my story with the world.

Xにもなって means "even after becoming X", so the correct answer is B.