# What てやったら in のませてやったら mean?

Tags: translation

What **てやったら** in のませてやったら mean?
Is it some conditional form of のませる verb? I can't find it in dicts.

And how would i translate the whole sentence:
おちちでも  のませてやったら  どーだ?

All i can assume is "How do you drink anything but milk?"

By the way, is どーだ equal to どう and means "how"?

And why だ is in the end of question sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What てやったら in のませてやったら mean? Is it some conditional form of のませる verb? I can't find it in dicts.

～てやったら is the conditional form of ～てやる. ～てやる is a less polite version of ～てあげる, "doing ~~ for someone's benefit". See [meaning of ～てやる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14416/9831).

のませてやったら is the conditional form of のませてやる.
のませてやる consists of the te-form of causative verb のませる + subsidiary
verb やる．

> And how would i translate the whole sentence: おちちでも のませてやったら どーだ?

To break it down to smaller chunks...

おちち -- breast, milk
でも* -- or something
のませてやったら -- if you let (someone) drink
どうだ -- how about...?

*For this usage of でも, see [Meaning of “でも” in “食事でもどうですか？”](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/21520/9831)・[The use of でも and ででも in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13464/9831)

Put together:
おちちでも のませてやったら どーだ?
"How about letting (someone) drink milk or something / suck the breast or something?"
"Why don't you give (someone) milk / the breast or something?"

> By the way, is どーだ equal to どう and means "how"?

Right. どーだ is どうだ, どう "how" + だ (copula).

> And why だ is in the end of question sentence?

It's quite normal, especially for males, to end a wh-question with だ in casual speech, as in
「～どうだ？」「～なんだ？」「～どこだ？」「～だれだ？」 etc.
「～だ？」 sounds rather masculine. Females would tend to say 「～どう？」「～なに？」「～どこ？」「～だれ？」 instead.